# Android OBJ Parser. Child Object over Parent Object. is it possible?

Tags: android, wavefront

is it possible to load 2 different OBJ's in one Parser?
I Mean Parent Object Maybe High Poly Male.obj and over it as a Child Object High Poly Shoulder.obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "in one Parser"? If a parser can load one file, it can load two...

An `OBJ`-file can contain data of multiple named objects. If you have multiple `OBJ` files, you'd have to parse each of the files individually.

An `OBJ` file is nothing more than a list of vertices, texture coordinates, normals, and information on how to construct the triangles. Which can be grouped into objects, with names. It supports also named groups. If the parser implementation you are using supports this information, you could take advantage of it.

If this doesn't clear things up, maybe you can clarify more what your understanding is.

Also, you tagged this with `android`. Is there a particular implementation you are using?